# Why is my if statement not returning the return statement?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple columns I want to check against one another. In this function, I have several if statements, below:

```
def bucketing(row):
    if row['NATIONALITY'] == 'RU' and row['party_other_nationality'] in other_party:
        return 'low risk'
    elif row['NATIONALITY'] == 'RU' and row['party_other_nationality'] not in other_party:
        return 'high risk'    
    
    if row['CTRY_RSD'] == 'RU' and row['NATIONALITY'] != 'RU' and row['CTRY_DMCL'] != 'RU' and row['INCORP_CNTRY'] != 'RUSSIA' and row['SOURCEOFWEALTH'] != 'RU':
        return 'low risk'
    else:
        return 'high risk'
    
    if row['CTRY_DMCL'] == 'RU' and row['NATIONALITY'] != 'RU' and row['CTRY_RSD'] != 'RU' and row['INCORP_CNTRY'] != 'RUSSIA' and row['SOURCEOFWEALTH'] != 'RU':
        return 'low risk'
    else:
        return 'high risk'
    
    if row['INCORP_CNTRY'] == 'RUSSIA' and row['NATIONALITY'] != 'RU' and row['CTRY_RSD'] != 'RU' and row['CTRY_DMCL'] != 'RU' and row['SOURCEOFWEALTH'] != 'RU':
        return 'low risk'
    else:
        return 'high risk'
    
    if row['SOURCEOFWEALTH'] == 'RU' and row['NATIONALITY'] != 'RU' and row['CTRY_RSD'] != 'RU' and row['CTRY_DMCL'] != 'RU' and row['INCORP_CNTRY'] != 'RUSSIAN FEDERATION':
        return 'low risk'
    elif row['SOURCEOFWEALTH'] == 'RU' and row['NATIONALITY'] == 'RU' or row['CTRY_RSD'] == 'RU' or row['CTRY_DMCL'] == 'RU' or row['INCORP_CNTRY'] == 'RUSSIAN FEDERATION':
        return 'high risk'
    elif row['SOURCEOFWEALTH'] != 'RU' and row['NATIONALITY'] != 'RU' and row['CTRY_RSD'] != 'RU' and row['CTRY_DMCL'] != 'RU' and row['INCORP_CNTRY'] != 'RUSSIAN FEDERATION':
        return 'No material link'
```

For each one, my understanding is as follows:
where I have written 'else', it would return 'high risk' if any of the second conditions after the 'and' is not met.

Example:

```
if row['CTRY_DMCL'] == 'RU' and row['NATIONALITY'] != 'RU' and row['CTRY_RSD'] != 'RU' and row['INCORP_CNTRY'] != 'RUSSIA' and row['SOURCEOFWEALTH'] != 'RU':
        return 'low risk'
    else:
        return 'high risk'
```

I would like this to return 'high risk', if the CTRY_DMCL column has 'RU' and any of the other columns have RU or RUSSIA.

The one that is not working is below:

```
   if row['SOURCEOFWEALTH'] == 'RU' and row['NATIONALITY'] != 'RU' and row['CTRY_RSD'] != 'RU' and row['CTRY_DMCL'] != 'RU' and row['INCORP_CNTRY'] != 'RUSSIAN FEDERATION':
        return 'low risk'
    elif row['SOURCEOFWEALTH'] == 'RU' and row['NATIONALITY'] == 'RU' or row['CTRY_RSD'] == 'RU' or row['CTRY_DMCL'] == 'RU' or row['INCORP_CNTRY'] == 'RUSSIAN FEDERATION':
        return 'high risk'
    elif row['SOURCEOFWEALTH'] != 'RU' and row['NATIONALITY'] != 'RU' and row['CTRY_RSD'] != 'RU' and row['CTRY_DMCL'] != 'RU' and row['INCORP_CNTRY'] != 'RUSSIAN FEDERATION':
        return 'No material link'
```

I do not get a low risk statement returned, if only 'SOURCEOFWEALTH' has a Russian value but nothing else does. This returns 'high risk'.

Could it be how I structured my function?

This is how I am running the function against my dataframe:
`merged['NEW COLUMN'] = merged.apply(bucketing, axis=1)`

I am now wondering if how I have written my if statements capture all of the conditions, or the very last one in each statement?

Thanks

Comment: Wdym does this logic make sense? Is this code giving you your desires output or not? Or is there some sort of error?

Comment: By make sense, I really mean my example I gave at the end. Would the if statement logic work there?

Comment: Again. Did you run this code? And was the actual output the same as your expected output? I dont think anyone wants to "check" your code while you havent even ran it

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my question with my specific problem after running the function.

Comment: Please show how you are calling this function.

Comment: Sure, this is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, in programming languages, whether it is Python, SQL, or others, whenever you combine `or` and `and` logical conditions, use parentheses to separate the conditions. If all conditions are joined with `and` types, then you would not need parentheses. Likely your second clause returns all conditions since it contains the mix of both types. See adjustment below:

```py
    if row['SOURCEOFWEALTH'] == 'RU' and row['NATIONALITY'] != 'RU' and row['CTRY_RSD'] != 'RU' and row['CTRY_DMCL'] != 'RU' and row['INCORP_CNTRY'] != 'RUSSIAN FEDERATION':
        return 'low risk'
    elif (row['SOURCEOFWEALTH'] == 'RU' and row['NATIONALITY'] == 'RU') or (row['CTRY_RSD'] == 'RU') or (row['CTRY_DMCL'] == 'RU') or (row['INCORP_CNTRY'] == 'RUSSIAN FEDERATION'):
        return 'high risk'
    elif row['SOURCEOFWEALTH'] != 'RU' and row['NATIONALITY'] != 'RU' and row['CTRY_RSD'] != 'RU' and row['CTRY_DMCL'] != 'RU' and row['INCORP_CNTRY'] != 'RUSSIAN FEDERATION':
        return 'No material link'
```

However, avoid rowwise conditional checks via `Series.apply` (hidden loop) for more vectorized operations like [**`numpy.select`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to assign *entire* column at once and not row by row. See draft below to be adjusted, completed, and tested:

```py
# LIST OF BOOLEAN ARRAY CONDITIONS (IDEALLY MUTUALLY EXCLUSIVE)
conditions = [
    (mydata['NATIONALITY'] == 'RU') & (mydata['party_other_nationality'].isin(other_party)),
    (mydata['NATIONALITY'] == 'RU') & (~mydata['party_other_nationality'].isin(other_party)),
    (mydata['CTRY_RSD'] == 'RU') & (mydata['NATIONALITY'] != 'RU') & (mydata['CTRY_DMCL'] != 'RU') & (mydata['INCORP_CNTRY'] != 'RUSSIA') & (mydata['SOURCEOFWEALTH'] != 'RU'),
    (mydata['CTRY_DMCL'] == 'RU') & (mydata['NATIONALITY'] != 'RU') & (mydata['CTRY_RSD'] != 'RU') & (mydata['INCORP_CNTRY'] != 'RUSSIA') & (mydata['SOURCEOFWEALTH'] != 'RU'),
    (mydata['SOURCEOFWEALTH'] == 'RU') & (mydata['NATIONALITY'] != 'RU') & (mydata['CTRY_RSD'] != 'RU') & (mydata['CTRY_DMCL'] != 'RU') & (mydata['INCORP_CNTRY'] != 'RUSSIAN FEDERATION')
     ...
]

# LIST OF RETURN VALUES (EQUAL LENGTH AS CONDITIONS)
choices = [
    'low risk', 'high risk', 'low risk', 'low risk', 'low risk', ...
]

mydata["new_risk_column"] = np.select(conditions, choices, default="No material link")
```

Comment: What an amazing and insightful answer, thanks.